# nginx move proxy app from subdomain to folder

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to move a ruby app from:
app.domain.com
To:
domain.com/app

Currently:

```
server_name app.domain.com    
location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:9001;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

Is it possible to set something like:

```
server_name domain.com 
location /app/ {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:9001;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

And add some directive in nginx that makes "domain.com/app/" the root of the application so I don't have to rewrite every path?
So that if the app has href="/" it translates to "domain.com/app/" instead of "domain.com/"?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `location` block back to what you had earlier, and change the `root` directive in your configuration, add `app/` to the end of the directive.

This way your web root directory will be current web root + `app/`.